# Load different colors based on conditions

Tags: android, xml

I am programming an application contains layouts with some views. I load these colors from `values/colors.xml`. Now, I want to define multiple themes for my application, e.g. `Blue` and `Green` (some sort of blue and green colors). My question is how can I define two `colors.xml` file and load it based on some conditions or choosing by user. What I want is some thing like `strings.xml` that we can load strings based on `locale` defined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, ScrollView with some buttons!

Comment: you can simply give the name of the colors as `choice1_tv1Color` for 1st choice and `choice2_tv1Color` for 2nd choice in the same `colors.xml`..

Comment: I know this, but I want some things like strings.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
string.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string name="white">#FFFFFF</string>
</resources>

values-fr/strings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="white">#EEEEEE</string>
</resources>


button.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.white)));
```

Comment: I think about this, but not any other way?